# Get Position of gesture Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, position, uigesturerecognizer

Right now I have two gestures, double tap and a single tap. The selector is:

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    CCLOG(@"Tap!");
}
```

I was wondering how to get the position of the tap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the recognizer's `locationInView:` method:

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    CCLOG(@"Tap!");
    CGPoint loc = [tapRecognizer locationInView:tapRecognizer.view];
}
```

Comment: Completely new to cocos2d, how do I find out what my view is?

Comment: @stenger96 The easiest would be to use `tapRecognizer.view`. You may need to translate the coordinate using `CGPoint glLoc = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:loc];`